# How can I make a method with a bounded type parameter exclude one subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, bounded-types

Let us assume that gibbons, orangutans, gorillas, chimpanzees and humans are all apes. I have modeled this relationship accordingly.

```
class Ape {}
class Gibbon extends Ape {}
class Orangutan extends Ape {}
class Gorilla extends Ape {}
class Chimpanzee extends Ape {}
class Human extends Ape {}
```

I now want to write a hunt() method with a bounded type parameter for hunting apes.

```
public static <T extends Ape> void hunt(T type) {}
```

Let us assume that there is nothing wrong with hunting non-human apes because they are just animals. However, hunting humans is wrong because it is murder. How can I re-write the above bounded type parameter to exclude humans as a legal parameter? I am not interested in exceptions here. I do not want the hunt() method to compile at all if invoked with a human parameter.

Comment: (That signature is equivalent to `public static void hunt(Ape type) {}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't exclude a specific subclass the way you intend there. What you can do however, is create an interface 'isHuntable', implemented by the required animals you want to hunt, and you use that as a type for your method instead of the generic type bound. Another maybe less elegant solution is to create another level in your hierarchy called 'Monkeys' for example which extend from Ape, having all the animals extending from it, and you use that Monkey type for your method. I'd go with the first approach though. You could use explicit type checking, but you'd be breaking the 'open-closed' principle in you code, so it's better to leverage those checks to the type system.

Just extending a bit on the concept of interface behaviour-contract which is powerful tool which is sadly underused. What you have among your Apes is a "is-a" relationship which tightly couples your subjects. Being "Huntable" on the other hand, is not an inherent or defining characteristic of the structure of that hierarchy, and is more an added condition/behaviour/check you'd like to add to a subset of that hierarchy. That is better achieved by adding contracts (interface implementation) to the subset you intend to have that behaviour. That will allow to add further contracts (interface implementations) in the future with minimal refactorings, maximal semantic clarity, less bugs and without tightly bounding a type to a behaviour. In short, you don't break the Liskov Substitution principle, nor the open closed principle, nor any SOLID principle.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's a way to do this.  You could make a sub-type of Ape that excludes Humans, or you can check for Humans as a type in the method itself (which would violate the Open-Closed principle) :

```
public static <T extends Ape> void hunt(T type) {
  if (type instanceOf Human) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("It's immoral to hunt Humans.  You monster.");
  }
  . . .
}
```

Comment: I like this answer best.  Program code should reflect program semantics.  Trying to model "real world objects" is almost always a mistake.  Introducing a new type gives the programmer the tool they need to implement this correctly.

Comment: Such `instanceof` check is obious violation of *Open Closed* principle

Comment: I don't want any exceptions, though. More than just make hunting humans morally illegal, I want to make it physically impossible in my program.

Comment: Of course code should reflect semantics, but that doesn't mean you are stuck with the first model that crosses your mind. As antkowicz mentions here, such explicit type checkings violate the Open-Closed principle.

Comment: An interface is often used as a behavioral contract, in this case you can have an interface 'isHuntable' which could be used by any animal hierarchy not restricted to monkeys, so; it's better not to hard-code your type hierarchy (Ape) to a behavioral restriction of your code. If you stick with your hierarchy for behavior checking, you won't be able add further behavioral contracts, like 'isMale' (if you want to further narrow down your hunting to animals that won't carry offsprings) as Java won't allow multiple inheritance. Better use interfaces for behavioral enforcements.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. There is no way to specify a bound to say "any subclass, except this one".

And even if you could, it wouldn't stop you invoking it:

```
chimp.hunt((Ape) human);
```

would get around it.

All you can do is to check this at runtime.

You could, via some tool such as [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info/) (written by Google, I am an employee, and I contribute; other tools are available) write a compile-time check to ensure that the argument is neither `Ape` nor `Human`; but that's outside the capabilities of "pure" Java.

Comment: I should have specified, but I would want generic apes and humans' ape ancestors to be huntable, just not humans themselves. Also, I meant for hunt() to be a static method of the Main class, so it cannot be invoked on an Ape object.

Comment: @KMan right, and my point that you can cast a `Human` to `Ape` was in expectation of that. The only way you could ever be sure at compile time that a `Human` won't be passed is by forbidding `Ape` as well.

Comment: I didn't make my hunt method invokable upon Ape objects because my intention was to create an ape-hunting program. I don't want apes to hunt other apes. Only the program may do so. chimp.hunt(human) implies that a chimpanzee is hunting humans, which brings to mind Planet of the Apes.

Comment: Understood. If I may wax philosophical, I suppose society often does cast Human to Ape in its execution of capital punishment.

Answer (score 1):

I would make your `hunt` method non-static; it's an action on the object itself, after all. Then, you can define the behavior for all Apes:

```
public void hunt() {
    this.die(); // oh no!
}
```

And of course, humans override that basic idea:

```
@Override
public void hunt() {
    throw new IllegalMurderException("Human horn hunting is against intergalactic law");
}
```

Adding a check for `#isHuntable` would be advisable, as keeping with the metaphor it's nice to know if you're allowed to hunt something before doing so. Additionally, I went with an exception for human hunting as it violates the general behavior of what you (well, I) would expect `#hunt` to achieve.

For the sake of overengineering and various concepts of SOLID, you can achieve this with a `Huntable` interface, which could extend a `Living` interface:

```
public interface Living {
    public void die();
}

public interface Huntable extends Living {
    default public void hunt() {
        this.die();
    }
    //could use this for a generic exception in the interface too
    public boolean isHuntable(); 
}

public interface Ape extends Huntable {} // already Huntable

public interface Human extends Ape {
    //And finally, we break that behavioral contract like above
}
```

Overall this makes your generics unnecessary. You'll be forced into a type cast and manual check if you go that route, as other answers have shown. So while it sidesteps the original question, I think this is a better solution to the underlying problem (XY problem?). More importantly, behavior concerning humans remains in a class describing humans.

**Edit:**

In keeping with the static method and a checked exception, *while I strongly recommend against it* (per my comments), you can use a method overload so `Human` objects go through a different signature:

```
public static void hunt(Ape example) { ... }

public static void hunt(Human example) throws HuntingException {
    throw new HuntingException("cannot hunt humans");
}
```

`HuntingException` would extend `Exception` instead of `RuntimeException`. `Exception`/`Error`/`Throwable` objects that you make yourself are all essentially checked exceptions. Short of that, there's no creating compiler errors yourself as a developer. You can generate warnings, but you face the same pitfalls.

You can kind of see why this is silly, and a human is still able to be hunted without a compiler error at all by just casting:

```
Main.hunt((Ape) someHuman);
```

So now you go back down the rabbit hole of adding type checks in your #hunt method, which won't throw a compiler error (or will have to *always* throw one). If you always throw it, then developers using your code (and quite possibly yourself) will just auto fill try-catch blocks around every single invocation of #hunt just to handle an error for `Human`. This adds a lot of "code noise", which just makes things messy.

In short, runtime exceptions are for developer errors like "hunting a human", and there's too many reasons to list for why having this as a static method (let alone main class) is not good from a design standpoint.

Comment: Hunt() is meant to be a static method in the Main class. Also, I would rather avoid exceptions. I wish to make any attempt at hunting humans not compile.

Comment: A compiler error (aka an uncaught checked exception) goes against the design paradigm for exceptions, they should be for things which are unavoidable errors (e.g. when reading a file, there may be a disk error, thus you must handle any `IOException` in your code to read it). Runtime errors, such as above, are for _developer or coding errors_, which is what Human#hunt would be. Lastly, why the restriction for static? And definitely why would it be located in the main class?

Comment: Overall, trying to tie a compiler error to even just the non-static method won't work; anyone would still be able to call it by assigning it to a parent-type variable or cast (e.g. `Ape`). However, there is a partial solution using a method overload for `Human` specifically, but again it's just plain bad design in my eyes. I'll add it to my answer, but I don't like it.